# Maven compilation: Failure executing javac

Tags: java, maven-2, stack-overflow

Here is an exception we get when trying to compile a freshly checked out code under Windows Server 2003 with Maven 2.2.1 and JDK 1.6.0_23. Several machines running Ubuntu with the same Maven and JDK version have no problems at all compiling the exact same source.

Have tried providing alternative Maven options (i.e. MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m) to no avail.

What could be the cause of this problem and what would be a possible solution? Thanx.

```
[INFO] Compilation failure

Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:


The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:1799)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1522)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:360)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:377)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1241)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1210)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:360)
   ... then trace repeats multiple times
```

Comment: `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m` will increase heap memory

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try

`MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss1024k`

Note: -Xss , should be set according to hardware available

Comment: Accepting this one as it was the first answer that worked. The answer by @dogbane is potentially more flexible as it is project related rather than system related (MAVEN_OPTS is an environment variable).

Comment: +1, as this helped me to figure out what I assume is the solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229020/jenkins-not-showing-maven-compiler-errors/10857174#10857174 (or at least was my problem, as detailed in my answer over there)

Answer (score 9):

Is any of your code being auto-generated e.g. from a WSDL? Can you pinpoint which class(es) is causing the problem? One way of doing this would be to remove some of your source, recompile and repeat until you have narrowed down to a small subset of classes.

Do you have any large classes or long methods? If so, you should refactor.

Increase the stack size. I think the default is 512k. Change the compiler configuration to:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <compilerArgument>-J -Xss10M</compilerArgument>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: +1 The compilerArgument didn't work for me (invalid javac argument for some reason). However compilerArguments (plural) did. As a side note, the maven documentation (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArguments) states that fork has to be set to true for the compilerArgument and compilerArguments to be used.

Comment: The most [recent documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) says that `<compilerArguments>` is now deprecated and you should use `<compilerArgs>` instead.

Comment: In maven 3.5.x it should be set like this:
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <arg>-J-Xss4m</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

Answer (score 2):

> What could be the cause of this problem and what would be a possible solution? Thanx.

Here are some possible causes:

- The stack is actually too small.  Fix - set a larger stack size.
- You are compiling a pathological class or method.  Fix - try and identify the file, identify the pathology, and refactor it.
- You've run into a java compiler bug.  Fix - try and identify the file, identify what is triggering the bug, and refactor it to workaround the bug.
- You've somehow managed to get a corrupt JAR file into the Maven local repository on the Windows machine.  Fix - wipe the repository and rebuild.  (This may entail re-downloading a bunch of artifacts and plugins.)

Answer (score 0):

I have also come across the same problem.
To fix it what I did, is-
I ran the below command in console

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss1024k *-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

instead of-

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss1024k *-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Try this, It would definitely work. If still you get same problem then replace

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

to

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: Moved to Java 8, which does not use permgen any longer.

Answer (score 0):

The comment below is a working answer

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss1024k -XX:MaxPermSize=384m"
```