# Maven webapp "javac: -endorseddirs requires an argument"

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a Maven webapp that uses the maven-compiler-plugin . A few days ago I could compile and run the app just fine, however something happened and compilation now fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: -endorseddirs requires an argument
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

It has something to do with the compiler but I can't understand it. Here's my pom.xml (just the plugins):

```xml
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I have tried some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782553/1333954).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `${endorsed.dir}` is not a standard Maven property. Have you copied this example from somewhere without replacing `${endorsed.dir}` with an actual value? Or did you have this value defined elsewhere in your `pom.xml`but it has been removed?

If this is the case, Maven would treat the field as blank and I can imagine the compiler would receive no argument for the `-endorseddirs` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler is not able to locate property `${endorsed.dir}` in you POM, Make sure it is defined in you POM. To check configuration of POM by `mvn help:effective-pom`, That will show actual POM after factoring all configuration.