# Maven Compilation Issue: The system is out of resources

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am aware that there are many who faced the same issue as I have. I am facing difficulty compiling it with the Maven Compiler Plugin using eclipse. I almost tried all the trouble shooting suggested by others. Any help would be great!

```
ERROR DETAILS:
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ WebScraper ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 12 source files to E:\Projects\Workspace\Repos\git\automateon2.0\WebScraper\target\classes
```

The system is out of resources. Consult the following stack trace for details.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:460)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Attr.java:2062)
at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(JCTree.java:1565)
```

Note: The above 4 lines are repeated 20 + times

```
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project WebScraper: Compilation failure
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Troubleshot with the following :

**1. Tried increasing the memory for the maven plugin's configuration node in pom.xml**

```
<argLine> -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine> 
MAVEN_OPTS = Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

**2. Tried setting up and increasing memory for the MAVEN_OPTS env variable**

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

**System Information:**

Windows 7 - 64 bit |  Compile Plugin Version: 3.1 |  Kepler 64

**Nature of my project:** Maven, TestNG project, with few java classes. I am using casperJs framework to scrape the data from the web pages and saving them on spreadsheet. I have used the js code as string in my java classes as I need to pass the Testng parameters. I  am keen on using maven compiler as I have to host this in Jenkins and execute maven commands. I am able to execute if I try to compile with Java with a main method and I am able to execute my project with testng.xml.
ex:

```java
@Test
public static String diceJS(String keyword, String Filepath)
{
    String filepath=Filepath.replace("\\", "/");
    String str="var casper=require('casper').create();"
    +"\n"+"var fs = require('fs');"
    +"\n"+"var key='"+keyword+"';"
    +"\n"+"var x=require('casper').selectXPath;"
::::::::::: THIS IS SAMPLE. THERE IS HUGE STRING THAT I HAVE TO USE :::::::::::     
}
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>WebScraper</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/test/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration> 
                <source>1.7</source> 
                <target>1.7</target>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xms768m -Xmx768m</extraJvmArgs> 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles> 
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <buildnumber>${build.number}</buildnumber>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <properties>

                </properties>
            </configuration> 
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: If you're getting a `StackOverflowError`, you almost certainly have runaway recursion somewhere. What happens when you run your tests outside of Maven (e.g., in Eclipse)?

Comment: I have tried compiling this through CLI using maven also in Eclipse using maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: sorry Chrylis, my wireless keyboard was hard pressed accidentally.

Comment: Will Eclipse compile the code? Did you run Maven with the suggested debug options?

Comment: A stack overflow in the compiler is strange. It  could be caused by an excessively complex source file. You mentioned a huge string in one of the source files. Try to get that from an external resource instead of hard coding it in the program.

Comment: have you tried the -Xss option as detailed in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4782553/1570834

Comment: My issue is resolved by adding "-Xss10m" to MAVEN_OPTS

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens in compile phase.

In my case, I solve this kind of problem doing this:

```
env MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Xss10m" mvn compiler:compile
```