# Scala: compilation error due to huge number of methods in chain

Tags: java, scala, compiler-errors

There is an object (java object generated from avro schema) with a builder. The object has a flat structure and contains about 200 fields.

The code looks as:

```
Object.newBuilder()
  .setField1()
  .setField2()
  ...
  .setField200()
```

The scala compiler in Idea compiles that without any problem. When I tried to run maven build - it failed with compilation problem: StackOverflow

```
 [ERROR] error: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 [INFO]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:666)
 [INFO]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5303)
 [INFO]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5330)
 [INFO]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5277)
 [INFO]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5281)
 [INFO]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5379)
 [INFO]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5387)
 [INFO]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:612)
 [INFO]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:666)
 [INFO]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5303)
```

Scala version: 2.11
Scala maven plugin: 3.3.1

As a workaround, I split set methods into the groups (for 100 setters in each chain)

```
val builder = Object.newBuilder()
builder.setField1()
  .setField2()
  ...
  .setField100()
builder.setField101()  
  ...
  .setField200()
```

That managed to compile on my local machine but failed to compile on Jenkins server. After I split the setters into smaller groups (30 setters in each group), the code compiled on Jenkins server also.

Is there any param that configures that behavior in scala compiler?

Comment: Maybe this can serve as a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782553/5761558?

Comment: @ernest_k, thanks,i had <jvmArg>-Xss4m</jvmArg>, tried wtih 10, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I used to suffer the same issue and I solved it by increasing of the stack size from default 1MB to 10MB. Hope it help!

Comment: Thanks. I had -Xss4m before, tried with 10m. Failed anyway. As this param the same for all env (my local machine and Jenkins server) i would assume the problem is in another place